# Celery multi doesn't launch scheduled tasks

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm a bit stuck with celery on flask,

I've prepared this schedule :

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
  'scandir-every-day': {
      'task': 'app.core.scanAllPackages',
      'schedule': crontab(hour='*/24')
  },
  'scandir-custo-package':{
      'task': 'app.core.scanCustomPackages',
      'schedule': crontab(minute='*/10')
  }
}
```

and Celery routes like this :

```
CELERY_ROUTES={
    'app.core.scanAllPackages':
        {
            "queue":"slow"
        },
    'app.core.scanCustomPackages':
        {
            "queue":"fast"
        }
}
```

I've created my celery object in app/__init__.py like this :

```
from extensions import make_celery
celery = make_celery(app)
```

and the make_celery method looks like this :

```
from celery import Celery
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

Every seems fine and I launch my workers like this :

```
celery multi start fast slow -c:slow 1 -c:fast 2 -A app:celery -l debug --verbose
```

and the beat is launched like this :

```
 celery beat -A app:celery --detach
```

Basicaly, nothing appends, the workers are just waiting,

```
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,182: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,182: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,182: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,186: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,187: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,187: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,206: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,206: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,207: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,213: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,213: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[2015-08-12 09:45:21,213: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,218: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,219: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,219: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,222: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,222: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,227: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,227: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,229: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,229: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,230: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,230: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,230: WARNING/MainProcess] fast@host01 ready.
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,230: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,231: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->8
[2015-08-12 09:45:22,932: DEBUG/MainProcess] slow@host01 joined the party
```

So if anyobdy had an idea of what's wrong with my beat ?
that would be great,
Thank you.

Comment: I've found `celery multi` tricky to work with. I'd suggest seeing if you can get this working by simply running 2 workers in the foreground - i.e. `celery worker -A app:celery -Q fast` and `celery worker -A app:celery -Q slow` and seeing if they pick up the tasks at the appropriate times

Comment: @scytale : launching celery worker twice works fine, it has retrieve the large amount of task not processed (that the beat had set up) ...  I don't understand why celery multi doesn't process the queue ...   I've also discovered that my app doesn't support concurrent execution (thank you Whoosh) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Like I say, I've found `celery multi` tricky - I would advise using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage the workers.